# Absolute positioning for nested elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

My problem relates to the following demos http://jsfiddle.net/legrass/ca22L/ and http://jsfiddle.net/legrass/eER66/2/.

In short, I need highlight some elements on a page (e.g., by a red border) but without touching the actual elements (to avoid affecting the original page's layout).
For that, in JS I create 'overlay' elements positioned absolutely upon the element to highlight using top, left coordinates. These are appended to body and styled via CSS (see first JSFiddle).
For instance:

```
<body>
<div class='overlay'>
<span class="a" style="top: 14px; left: 321px; width: 200px; height: 140px;"> </span>
<span class="b" style="top: 52px; left: 351px; width: 140px; height: 63px;"> </span>
<span class="c" style="top: 72px; left: 400px; width: 8px; height: 16px;"></span>
<span class="c" style="top: 74px; left: 420px; width: 8px; height: 16px;"></span>
</div>
....
```

That works fine. However, to allow more flexible css selectors (e.g., child), I need to build the above overlays by nesting them like:

```
<body>
<div class='overlay'>
<span class="a" style="top: 14px; left: 321px; width: 200px; height: 140px;">
   <span class="b" style="top: 52px; left: 351px; width: 140px; height: 63px;">
      <span class="c" style="top: 72px; left: 400px; width: 8px; height: 16px;"></span>
      <span class="c" style="top: 74px; left: 420px; width: 8px; height: 16px;"></span>
   <span/>
<span/>
</div>
....
```

The nesting can be at any depth. Unfortunately now the positioning it's incorrect, (see second JSFiddle).

I understand that it is because each span is now positioned absolutely but with respect to its parent, and not anymore to the single container div. I have tried relative positioning but doesn't work of course.

QUESTION: Is there a way to obtain the layout as in the first JSfiddle but maintaining span the hierarchy??

**UPDATE**
From the answer below, adjusting the coordinates by using offsetLeft and offsetTop really helps.  I compute the total offset going up the DOM and adding  offsetLeft (offsetTop) until offsetParent exists. 
However, the result is still few pixels shifted, it seems there is something else to be taken into account. Any idea?

**SOLVED**
As mentioned below in the comments, it is necessary to consider also border width.

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two JsFiddle... Hint: an absolute positioned element's parent must be `position:relative` in order for the absolute positioned one to lay out correctly.

Comment: Sorry now the fiddle shoud be ok. I learned about that, but my problem is that I have absolute coordinates (w.r.t. the viewport) on which the elements need to be layed, and also I have a potentially unbounded chain of them nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, CSS does *not* have a way to position element other than relative to its *closest* ancestor positioned relatively or absolutely. But since you use JS, you can change offset (`left`, `top`) for each element according to offsets of its ancestor elements and achieve needed results.

Improved version (taking borders into account) of Quirks mode [function](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html):

```js
function getCssPropertyValue(elem, prop) {
    return window.getComputedStyle
         // Modern browsers.
         ? window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop)
         // IE8 and older.
         : elem.currentStyle.getAttribute(prop);
}

function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;

    if (!obj.offsetParent) {
        return;
    }

    do {
        curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop  += obj.offsetTop;

        // If not Opera and not IE8 (see http://tanalin.com/en/articles/ie-version-js/ )
        // Opera and IE8 return incorrect values otherwise.
        if (!window.opera && (!document.all || document.addEventListener || !document.querySelector)) {
            var blw = parseInt(getCssPropertyValue(obj, 'border-left-width'), 10),
                btw = parseInt(getCssPropertyValue(obj, 'border-top-width'), 10);

            if (blw) {
                curleft += blw;
            }

            if (btw) {
                curtop += btw;
            }
        }
    }
    while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

    return [curleft, curtop];
}
```

**Update:** A more clear, compact, fast, precise, future-proof and bullet-proof solution is to use [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect):

```js
function getElementCoords(elem) {
    var root  = document.documentElement,
        body  = document.body,
        sTop  = window.pageYOffset || root.scrollTop  || body.scrollTop,
        sLeft = window.pageXOffset || root.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft,
        cTop  = root.clientTop  || body.clientTop  || 0,
        cLeft = root.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0,
        rect  = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        top   = Math.round(rect.top  + sTop  - cTop),
        left  = Math.round(rect.left + sLeft - cLeft);

    return {
        top  : top,
        left : left
    };
}
```

By the way, consider using jQuery's [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset1) where crossbrowser inconsistencies are already worked around out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped! I compute the whole offset going up the Dom (as explained [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)) and subtract it to set the absolute position. However, the result is still few pixels shifted, it's like I should something else. Am I computing the offset wrongly?

Comment: Do you take borders into account?

Comment: Not really, do you mean the width? How would you do that?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are positioned from padding-box (not border-box) of its closest positioned ancestor. If ancestor has, e.g. `border: 5px`, then top left corner of the ancestor's border will be shifted for 5px to the left/top from top left corner of its internal area not including border. So you most likely should add border width of each positioned ancestor to your total offset.

Comment: I've added code example containing improved version of Quirks-mode function.

Comment: Great effort and thanks for your time. It is definitively a problem of taking into account borders. However, I spent a bit to understand that it is needed only to cumulate the offsets of the ancestors, and not including also the elements itself (just invoking the function findPos with the offsetParent of the element at hand).

Answer (score 2):

You can use outline to add a border without affecting the box model.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately I need to do more sophisticated highlighting (e.g., showing infos), and for text nodes I compute the range and draw a corresponding styled box.

Comment: You can use pseudo elements. It would be better if you could give us more specefic information of what you are trying to do.
You can also use `box-sizing: border-box`so as not to alter the layout, but to have more flexibility with borders.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` makes an element's positioning relative to the first non-statically positioned ancestor (in other words, "absolute" is actually relative!). Since your containing spans are not statically positioned (they are absolutely positioned), the contained spans are positioned relative to their parents, not `.overlay`. The only way to get the same effect is to account for the cumulative offsets of all ancestors, and set top, left, etc. accordingly.

PS: It's a little odd to use spans for your rectangles, because they are in-line elements, rather than block elements. Why don't you use div instead? Shouldn't change the result, but divs seem like the right thing for you to use.

Comment: yes you're right about span v div, I'll change that thanks. And yes, indeed I solved by cumulating the offset of all ancestors